# Get number of days from today from last non-zero value recorded in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table that contains data for different individuals on daily basis.
I want to fetch the most-recent date from the table and the number of days between the most-recent date and current date where the individual has recorded a non-zero value. And if the value is zero for all the dates for an individual, then it should return me the first record that recorded the 0 value.

If this is the data on `2022-09-28`

```
| id | region | value | date       |
|----|--------|-------|------------|
| 1  | IN     | 0     | 2022-06-01 |
| 1  | IN     | 1     | 2022-06-02 |
| 1  | IN     | 0     | 2022-06-03 |
| 2  | US     | 23    | 2022-06-01 |
| 2  | US     | 1     | 2022-06-02 |
| 2  | US     | 0     | 2022-06-03 |
| 3  | EU     | 0     | 2022-06-01 |
| 3  | EU     | 0     | 2022-06-02 |
| 3  | EU     | 0     | 2022-06-03 |
| 4  | EU     | 2     | 2022-06-01 |
| 4  | EU     | 0     | 2022-06-02 |
| 4  | EU     | 0     | 2022-06-03 |
| 5  | CN     | 2     | 2022-06-01 |
| 5  | CN     | 3     | 2022-06-02 |
| 5  | CN     | 5     | 2022-06-03 |
```

Then the result I am required to get is

```
| id | region | value | date       | daysFromToday |
|----|--------|-------|------------|---------------|
| 1  | IN     | 1     | 2022-06-02 | 119           |
| 2  | US     | 1     | 2022-06-02 | 119           |
| 3  | EU     | 0     | 2022-06-01 | 120           |
| 4  | EU     | 2     | 2022-06-01 | 120           |
| 5  | CN     | 5     | 2022-06-03 | 118           |
```

I am able to identify the individual who have recorded all zero values by using this query.
But for all other individuals how should I get the values?

```
SELECT
    id, 
    region,
    SUM(value) as value_sum,
    MIN(date) 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY
    id 
HAVING value_sum= 0;
```

**Update:**

I am able to get partial solution.
With this query I am able to get id, region and daysFromToday but value is not coming correct because of the `group by` clause.

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        region, 
        SUM(`value`) AS sum_values,
        MIN(date) AS min_date
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY id, region
    HAVING sum_values = 0
),
UNION_CTE2 AS (
    SELECT 
        CTE1.id,
        CTE1.region, 
        CTE1.min_date AS `date`,
        DATEDIFF( now(), CTE1.min_date) AS `daysFromToday`
    FROM CTE1
    UNION
    SELECT 
        T.id,
        T.region,
        MAX(T.date) AS `date`,
        DATEDIFF( now(), MAX(T.date)) AS `daysFromToday`
    FROM tbl AS T
    WHERE `value` > 0 
    GROUP BY
        id, 
        region
)

SELECT * FROM UNION_CTE2;
```

Comment: 3  | EU     | 0     | 2022-06-03 - date should be 2022-06-01 for first??

Comment: My bad. Yes, it should be 2022-06-01.

Corrected the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

work out the max date for those which have values join to source then union those that don't have values on the basis that max(value) is 0

```
select t.id,t.region,t.value,t.date
from t
join
(select id,region,max(date) date 
from t 
where value <> 0 
group by id,region)s on s.id = t.id and s.region = t.region and s.date = t.date
union all
select t1.id , t1.region,0,min(t1.date) 
from t t1 
group by t1.id,t1.region having max(value) = 0 
order by id,region;

+------+--------+-------+------------+
| id   | region | value | date       |
+------+--------+-------+------------+
|    1 | IN     |     1 | 2022-06-02 |
|    2 | US     |     1 | 2022-06-02 |
|    3 | EU     |     0 | 2022-06-01 |
|    4 | EU     |     2 | 2022-06-01 |
|    5 | CN     |     5 | 2022-06-03 |
+------+--------+-------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```